# Inno setup : how to check if the service is already installed or not?

Tags: windows, service, inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to create an installer for "winscp(an application) updater". For that first i have prepared how to achieve that.The following things are i need to do

1. first check whether the "winscp" is installed or not
2. if it is installed check which version of winscp it is?
3. then compare current version of winscp and updated version of winscp(it will be there on internet downloads)
4. if current version number is lower than updated version number then download that version
5. then install that updated winscp version

if you have any idea, please help me to do it.

Comment: Any luck on this?  Looking for the same thing.

Comment: Yes we done, here i was taken as example as winscp but actually i was looking for another software. How ever me and my friend has fixed this. I will let you know the process in my next comment